# Calculating the intersection between Ellipse (from fitellipse function opencv) and a line (having its start and ending point)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ellipse, hough-transform

i have an image of soccer pitch, i am trying to detect the intersections between Landmarks on the pitch, one of the main landmarks are the intersection between ellipses (middle circle, 18 yards box circle) and lines (Middle line, and 18 yards box lines)

I managed to detect the lines using houghtransform, and managed to detect the ellipses using contours and fitellipse opencv method,

How can i get the intersection between them?

Comment: using simple math. What's the actual programming problem?

Comment: The programming problem is that i have ellipse in the form of (X-Center,Y-Center,Major axis length, Minor axis length, angle)
And a line of the form (Start-X,Start-Y,End-X,End-Y)

So is there anything easier than converting them to a mathematical equation and solve them? using OpenCV & Python

Comment: There is the OpenCV function `cv::pointPolygonTest()` where you can test if a point is inside (=1), outside (=-1) or on a **contour** (=0). You could use a `cv::LineIterator` to access the pixels on your line. IMO that is not easier than just using math (e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse-LineIntersection.html).

Comment: Problem is i need to specify those points inside the program to get a homography based on these extracted points, so all of this must be done inside the script,

Comment: I see `opencv` in tags, but maybe you can use something else? I was detecting intersections of Polygons with https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html, I don't see functions for ellipse intersections, but You can calculate few points for each ellipse, then create Polygon and You will have "almost" intersection of ellipses